# SAS and INTNX formatting

Tags: date, sas

I am trying to see if a variable falls into a boundary of dates. 
I hate a DATE1 already in MMDDYY10.

I use the following code

```
DATA GIANT; 
  SET GIANT; 
  UPPER_BOUND= intnx('week', DATE1, 2);  
run;
```

it gives me back something in `Num 8`.

I want to restore it to `MMDDYY10.` so that I can compare it to my other dates.

Two Questions:

1. How can I convert a NUMERIC of length 8 into a date?
2. Why does intnx ... designed to work with dates return a numeric and not something in the same format?

I tried to convert it like this:

```
DATA GIANT; 
  SET GIANT; 
  UP_DATE=INPUT(PUT(UPPER_BOUND, 8.), MMDDYY10.);
  FORMAT UP_DOS MMDDYY10.; 
run;
```

but now it all comes up as null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SAS Dates are always numeric (# of days since 1/1/1960).  Date formats are simply a way of making that numeric readable.  INTNX returns a numeric because that's all a date is; it's up to you to apply a date format to the new variable.

In your case it's very simple.  You almost got it right in your attempt, but you don't need the input/put business.

```
data giant;
  set giant;
  upper_bound=intnx('week',Date1,2);
  format upper_bound MMDDYY10.;
run;
```

`INPUT` converts human readable text into a value (usually a number).  PUT converts a value into human readable text.  `PUT(INPUT(...))` is commonly used to convert a formatted value into a different kind of formatted value (for example, to convert the string "1/1/1960" to "01JAN1960"); `INPUT(PUT(...))` is not very commonly used unless you are parsing the string that `PUT` created (such as, to read just a particular date element or something like that).  Both change the type (from numeric to character in PUT or other way in INPUT) in most cases and certainly change the actual stored value.

Applying a format to a numeric column leaves the column as a numeric (which is usually good) but tells SAS how to display that numeric so you can understand it (also usually good).  So underneath the value is `19857` but what is displayed is `05/14/2014`.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! That makes more sense.